# JS change to HTML blinks out

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to do a radio button checker with HTML and java script. When I click the 'check' button, it changes the inner-html to a paragraph. For some reason, the text only shows for about a half second then disappears.

JS file:

```
function runQuestionCheck() {
    var question_one_answer = 1;
    var question_two_answer = 1;
    var question_three_answer = 1;

    var question_one_explanation = "Text explaining why that's stupid!";
    var question_two_explanation = " ";
    var question_three_explanation = " ";

    var question_one = document.getElementById("question_1").childNodes;
    if (question_one[question_one_answer].isChecked) {
        document.getElementById("q1_response").class = "correct";
        document.getElementById("q1_response").innerHTML = "Correct!";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("q1_response").innerHTML = ("Sorry, that's incorrect." +     question_one_explanation);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- Init CSS -->
    <style>
        html {
            background-image: url("../Pictures/bg_france.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        .center {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 20%;
        }

        .right {
            position: absolute;
            right: 1cm;
        }

        .left {
            position: absolute;
            left: 1cm;
        }

        .button_left {
            position: absolute;
            left: 1cm;
            color: blue;
        }

        .button_right {
            position: absolute;
            right: 1cm;
            color: blue;
        }

        .correct {
            color: green;
        }

        .incorrect {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Init head -->
    <head>
        <a href="home.html">
            <div class="button_left">
                Back to Home
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="sub_france.html">
            <div class="button_right">
                Highlight facts
            </div>
        </a>
        <title>
            France
        </title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../Pictures/beck_icon.png">
    </head>

    <!-- Init question script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScripts/questions_spain.js"></script>

    <!-- Init body -->
    <body>
        <br>
        <FONT FACE="arial">
        <!-- Title -->
            <h1>
                America and France
            </h1>
        <!-- Body/Info -->
            <p>
                This is where the info would go.
            </p>
            <br>
        <!-- Questions -->
            <hr>
            <h1>Comprehension Questions</h1>
            <form id="question_1">
                This is the first question!
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="q1_one">Answer one<br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" id="q1_two" value="green">Answer two<br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" id="q1_three" value="blue">Answer three<br>
            </form>
            <p id="q1_response"></p>
            <br>
            <form id="question_2">
                This is the second question!
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="q2_one">Answer one<br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" id="q2_two" value="green">Answer two<br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" id="q2_three" value="blue">Answer three<br>
            </form>
            <p id="q2_response"></p>
            <br>
            <form id="question_3">
                This is the third question!
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="q3_one">Answer one<br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" id="q3_two" value="green">Answer two<br>
                <input type="radio" name="color" id="q3_three" value="blue">Answer three<br>
            </form>
            <br>
            <form>
                <button onclick="runQuestionCheck()">Check answers!</button>
            </form>
            <p id="q3_response"></p>
            <br>
        </FONT>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery instead of pure javascript?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious but it's hard to tell without the HTML also. Is there perhaps other JavaScript on the page that could be unintentionally changing the innerHTML?

Comment: @JohnnyDew No idea how... could you give an example?

Comment: post your HTML code .

Comment: advise create a http://jsfiddle.net for others easily check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing only a flash of text is because the text is being displayed, and then the *page is immediately being refreshed.* That's caused by the fact that your check button is inside a form.  Since the form doesn't have an `action` or a `method` set, it defaults to submitting to the current page, via GET, which is basically the same as refreshing the page.

Looking at your code, you have a lot of forms that you probably don't need.  You're not sending the data anywhere, you're just checking it locally in JavaScript.  However, to remove all of them, your JavaScript code would need to be significantly overhauled, so to avoid that you can solve this problem either of these two ways:

**Removing the `form` from your button**

Right now it's not doing anything at all.  Just get rid of it and you won't have a problem.  Replace

```
<form>
    <button onclick="runQuestionCheck()">Check answers!</button>
</form>
```

With

```
<button onclick="runQuestionCheck()">Check answers!</button>
```

Or, **Add a `type` attribute to the button**

The button defaults to being a submit button, which will submit whatever form it's in when it's clicked.  That's what we want to avoid, so you can instead set it to be just a normal button, like this:

```
<form>
    <button onclick="runQuestionCheck()" type="button">Check answers!</button>
</form>
```

If you want to keep the form, then this is your best option.

Your code has some other problems, too.

- Your `style` should go in the `head`.
- Your links (Back to Home and Highlight facts) should not be in the `head`, they should be in the `body`.  Content never goes in the `head`.
- Your `script` can't just be in the middle of nowhere.  It has to go in either the `head` or the `body`.  Nowadays it's generally recommended to put it in the `body`.
- You shouldn't use `FONT` tags to style your text, you should use CSS.  To put everything in Arial, you can put this in your `style` tag:

  ```
  body {
      font-family: arial;
  }
  ```
- Your JavaScript will encounter an error.  The correct way to change an element's class in JavaScript is `className`.  Replace this:

  ```
  document.getElementById("q1_response").class = "correct";
  ```

  With this:

  ```
  document.getElementById("q1_response").className = "correct";
  ```